# Google Map Services Java public transit line numbers

Tags: java, google-maps

I'm trying out this library:
https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java/

Has anyone figured out how to find line numbers in transit search? DirectionsStep.java says:

When using the Directions API to search for transit directions, the steps array will include additional [Transit Details](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/#TransitDetails) in the form of a {@code transitDetails} array.

Using a debugger I can't figure out where this transitDetails array should be found, any help? I get bus instructions and have set

```
directions.mode(TravelMode.TRANSIT);
```

and otherwise it works very well, but I can't find the line numbers.

(Could be tagged with a new tag google-maps-services-java)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the line number using the Direction API in the TRANSIT mode.

If you see the Google's Official Documentation, in the response there is a object returned in the line object called the **short_name**.

I used the following request:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=timesSquare&destination=brooklyn&mode=transit

And if you search for short_name it will give you the line number.

Hope this Helps!!